# How to unsubscribe @Output as Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a question about unsubscribing `Output`s in Angular. I know that EventEmitter gets cleaned up automatically, but the last time I needed use `Observable` as my `Output`. I mean, I wanted take `Output` which emit maximum once event per second. So my code looked like:

```
@Output() loadNextEvent: Observable<any>;
loadNextSubject = new Subject();

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.loadNextEvent = this.loadNextSubject.asObservable()
        .throttleTime(1000); // once per second
    }

emit() {
    this.loadNextSubject.next('new event');
}
```

Ok, it works pretty fine - I thought. The only problem is unsubscribing. I found [one solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription) on StackOverflow, but I'm still not sure, how I should do it correctly. In my case:

```
@Output() loadNextEvent: Observable<any>;
loadNextSubject = new Subject();

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.loadNextEvent = this.loadNextSubject.asObservable()
        .takeUntil(this.loadNextSubject) //does it make any sense?
        .throttleTime(1000); // once per second
    }

emit() {
    this.loadNextSubject.next('new event');
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.loadNextSubject.complete();
}
```

**Question:**
Is this the correct unsubscribing of `observable Output`? `.takeUntil(this.loadNextSubject)` make any sense? Or maybe `.asObservable()` give ensurance that Observable was cleaned, when `Subject` is completed? Anyone know answer for my problem? or maybe, there is a better solution, then use `Observable` as `Output`, for my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `takeUntil` the notifier Observable needs to emit a `next` notification and not just complete. So the correct way to do this would be like this:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.loadNextSubject.next();
    this.loadNextSubject.complete();
}
```

Also you don't need to use `asObservable()` in this case. Subjects are Observables so using `asObservable()` will just wrap it with another Observable which is unnecessary.

One more thing. In Angular 5 there's a bug that is creating memory leaks when chaining operators with `EventEmitter` (the chain wasn't properly disposed). For more details you can have a look here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21999.

This was fixed here https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/22016 and should be available since Angular 6.

And I think this is exactly what you're doing right now. An easy way to avoid this until Angular 6 is actually using `asObservable()` before adding any operators (see this comment https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21999#issuecomment-362921475).

Comment: so if I will not use `.takeUntil(this.loadNextSubject)`, can I add only `this.loadNextSubject.complete();` in `ngOnDestroy`? Or `.takeUntil(this.loadNextSubject)` is required for this structure and I have to add `this.loadNextSubject.next();` too (before .complete).

Comment: If you want to use `.takeUntil(this.loadNextSubject)` you have to `this.loadNextSubject.next();`. Without it it wont work.